# При подключении плагина плавного скролла элементы позиционируются неправильно

Tags: css, вёрстка

всем привет. такая проблема - хочу прикрутить к сайту плагин для смягчения скролла(по идее не имеет значения какой).При подключении подобных плагинов тегам `body` и `html` нужно присваивать `height:100%;`.Но если я делаю это, то отображение элементов на странице становится неправильным - секция с основным контентом занимает не всю ширину экрана, а вот footer всю и получается неправильный слоеный пирог.Вот пример кода:

```css
.wrapper {
position:relative;
z-index:11;
}
.site-content {
margin:10px auto 500px; //это для создания слоя над футером
max-width:1263px;
width:100%;
}
.footer {
box-sizing:content-box;
height:500px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<section class="site-content">
<p>Тут контент сайта</p>
</section>
</div>
<footer>
<p>Тут расположены какие-то элементы навигации</p>
</footer>
```

Пока не добавляю к `body` и `html` cвойство `height:100%;` все нормально отображается, а если добавить, то отображение ломается.Я понимаю что проблема в том, что у `footer` стоит `position:fixed`;-потому что если изменить на `relative`, то все работает нормально.Отказываться не хочу от подобного эффекта с футером, поэтому кто может подсказать как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [SmoothScroll](https://github.com/themicon/smoothscroll).

Этот плагин не требует установки `height:100%;` для `html` и `body`.

Рабочий [пример](https://codepen.io/Cheg/pen/rwZYRE) (откройте в режиме `Full Page`).

```js
/* SmoothScroll v0.9.9 | Licensed under the terms of the MIT license. | People involved - Balazs Galambosi: maintainer (CHANGELOG.txt) - Patrick Brunner (patrickb1991@gmail.com) - Michael Herf: ssc_pulse Algorithm*/
  var ssc_framerate=150;var ssc_animtime=500;var ssc_stepsize=150;var ssc_pulseAlgorithm=true;var ssc_pulseScale=6;var ssc_pulseNormalize=1;var ssc_keyboardsupport=true;var ssc_arrowscroll=50;var ssc_frame=false;var ssc_direction={x:0,y:0};var ssc_initdone=false;var ssc_fixedback=true;var ssc_root=document.documentElement;var ssc_activeElement;var ssc_key={left:37,up:38,right:39,down:40,spacebar:32,pageup:33,pagedown:34,end:35,home:36};function ssc_init(){if(!document.body){return;}var body=document.body;var html=document.documentElement;var windowHeight=window.innerHeight;var scrollHeight=body.scrollHeight;ssc_root=(document.compatMode.indexOf("CSS")>=0)?html:body;ssc_activeElement=body;ssc_initdone=true;if(top!=self){ssc_frame=true;}else{if(scrollHeight>windowHeight&&(body.offsetHeight<=windowHeight||html.offsetHeight<=windowHeight)){ssc_root.style.height="auto";if(ssc_root.offsetHeight<=windowHeight){var underlay=document.createElement("div");underlay.style.clear="both";body.appendChild(underlay);}}}if(!ssc_fixedback){body.style.backgroundAttachment="scroll";html.style.backgroundAttachment="scroll";}if(ssc_keyboardsupport){ssc_addEvent("keydown",ssc_keydown);}}var ssc_que=[];var ssc_pending=false;function ssc_scrollArray(elem,left,top,delay){delay||(delay=1000);ssc_directionCheck(left,top);ssc_que.push({x:left,y:top,lastX:(left<0)?0.99:-0.99,lastY:(top<0)?0.99:-0.99,start:+new Date});if(ssc_pending){return;}var step=function(){var now=+new Date;var scrollX=0;var scrollY=0;for(var i=0;i<ssc_que.length;i++){var item=ssc_que[i];var elapsed=now-item.start;var finished=(elapsed>=ssc_animtime);var position=(finished)?1:elapsed/ssc_animtime;if(ssc_pulseAlgorithm){position=ssc_pulse(position);}var x=(item.x*position-item.lastX)>>0;var y=(item.y*position-item.lastY)>>0;scrollX+=x;scrollY+=y;item.lastX+=x;item.lastY+=y;if(finished){ssc_que.splice(i,1);i--;}}if(left){var lastLeft=elem.scrollLeft;elem.scrollLeft+=scrollX;if(scrollX&&elem.scrollLeft===lastLeft){left=0;}}if(top){var lastTop=elem.scrollTop;elem.scrollTop+=scrollY;if(scrollY&&elem.scrollTop===lastTop){top=0;}}if(!left&&!top){ssc_que=[];}if(ssc_que.length){setTimeout(step,delay/ssc_framerate+1);}else{ssc_pending=false;}};setTimeout(step,0);ssc_pending=true;}function ssc_wheel(event){if(!ssc_initdone){ssc_init();}var target=event.target;var overflowing=ssc_overflowingAncestor(target);if(!overflowing||event.defaultPrevented||ssc_isNodeName(ssc_activeElement,"embed")||(ssc_isNodeName(target,"embed")&&/\.pdf/i.test(target.src))){return true;}var deltaX=event.wheelDeltaX||0;var deltaY=event.wheelDeltaY||0;if(!deltaX&&!deltaY){deltaY=event.wheelDelta||0;}if(Math.abs(deltaX)>1.2){deltaX*=ssc_stepsize/120;}if(Math.abs(deltaY)>1.2){deltaY*=ssc_stepsize/120;}ssc_scrollArray(overflowing,-deltaX,-deltaY);event.preventDefault();}function ssc_keydown(event){var target=event.target;var modifier=event.ctrlKey||event.altKey||event.metaKey;if(/input|textarea|embed/i.test(target.nodeName)||target.isContentEditable||event.defaultPrevented||modifier){return true;}if(ssc_isNodeName(target,"button")&&event.keyCode===ssc_key.spacebar){return true;}var shift,x=0,y=0;var elem=ssc_overflowingAncestor(ssc_activeElement);var clientHeight=elem.clientHeight;if(elem==document.body){clientHeight=window.innerHeight;}switch(event.keyCode){case ssc_key.up:y=-ssc_arrowscroll;break;case ssc_key.down:y=ssc_arrowscroll;break;case ssc_key.spacebar:shift=event.shiftKey?1:-1;y=-shift*clientHeight*0.9;break;case ssc_key.pageup:y=-clientHeight*0.9;break;case ssc_key.pagedown:y=clientHeight*0.9;break;case ssc_key.home:y=-elem.scrollTop;break;case ssc_key.end:var damt=elem.scrollHeight-elem.scrollTop-clientHeight;y=(damt>0)?damt+10:0;break;case ssc_key.left:x=-ssc_arrowscroll;break;case ssc_key.right:x=ssc_arrowscroll;break;default:return true;}ssc_scrollArray(elem,x,y);event.preventDefault();}function ssc_mousedown(event){ssc_activeElement=event.target;}var ssc_cache={};setInterval(function(){ssc_cache={};},10*1000);var ssc_uniqueID=(function(){var i=0;return function(el){return el.ssc_uniqueID||(el.ssc_uniqueID=i++);};})();function ssc_setCache(elems,overflowing){for(var i=elems.length;i--;){ssc_cache[ssc_uniqueID(elems[i])]=overflowing;}return overflowing;}function ssc_overflowingAncestor(el){var elems=[];var ssc_rootScrollHeight=ssc_root.scrollHeight;do{var cached=ssc_cache[ssc_uniqueID(el)];if(cached){return ssc_setCache(elems,cached);}elems.push(el);if(ssc_rootScrollHeight===el.scrollHeight){if(!ssc_frame||ssc_root.clientHeight+10<ssc_rootScrollHeight){return ssc_setCache(elems,document.body);}}else{if(el.clientHeight+10<el.scrollHeight){overflow=getComputedStyle(el,"").getPropertyValue("overflow");if(overflow==="scroll"||overflow==="auto"){return ssc_setCache(elems,el);}}}}while(el=el.parentNode);}function ssc_addEvent(type,fn,bubble){window.addEventListener(type,fn,(bubble||false));}function ssc_removeEvent(type,fn,bubble){window.removeEventListener(type,fn,(bubble||false));}function ssc_isNodeName(el,tag){return el.nodeName.toLowerCase()===tag.toLowerCase();}function ssc_directionCheck(x,y){x=(x>0)?1:-1;y=(y>0)?1:-1;if(ssc_direction.x!==x||ssc_direction.y!==y){ssc_direction.x=x;ssc_direction.y=y;ssc_que=[];}}function ssc_pulse_(x){var val,start,expx;x=x*ssc_pulseScale;if(x<1){val=x-(1-Math.exp(-x));}else{start=Math.exp(-1);x-=1;expx=1-Math.exp(-x);val=start+(expx*(1-start));}return val*ssc_pulseNormalize;}function ssc_pulse(x){if(x>=1){return 1;}if(x<=0){return 0;}if(ssc_pulseNormalize==1){ssc_pulseNormalize/=ssc_pulse_(1);}return ssc_pulse_(x);}var ie=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/msie|Trident/i);if(ie==null){ssc_addEvent("mousedown",ssc_mousedown);ssc_addEvent("mousewheel",ssc_wheel);ssc_addEvent("load",ssc_init);}(function($){$.fn.appear=function(f,o){var s=$.extend({one:true},o);return this.each(function(){var t=$(this);t.appeared=false;if(!f){t.trigger("appear",s.data);return;}var w=$(window);var c=function(){if(!t.is(":visible")){t.appeared=false;return;}var a=w.scrollLeft();var b=w.scrollTop();var o=t.offset();var x=o.left;var y=o.top;if(y+t.height()>=b&&y<=b+w.height()&&x+t.width()>=a&&x<=a+w.width()){if(!t.appeared){t.trigger("appear",s.data);}}else{t.appeared=false;}};var m=function(){t.appeared=true;if(s.one){w.unbind("scroll",c);var i=$.inArray(c,$.fn.appear.checks);if(i>=0){$.fn.appear.checks.splice(i,1);}}f.apply(this,arguments);};if(s.one){t.one("appear",s.data,m);}else{t.bind("appear",s.data,m);}w.scroll(c);$.fn.appear.checks.push(c);(c)();});};$.extend($.fn.appear,{checks:[],timeout:null,checkAll:function(){var l=$.fn.appear.checks.length;if(l>0){while(l--){($.fn.appear.checks[l])();}}},run:function(){if($.fn.appear.timeout){clearTimeout($.fn.appear.timeout);}$.fn.appear.timeout=setTimeout($.fn.appear.checkAll,20);}});$.each(["append","prepend","after","before","attr","removeAttr","addClass","removeClass","toggleClass","remove","css","show","hide"],function(i,n){var u=$.fn[n];if(u){$.fn[n]=function(){var r=u.apply(this,arguments);$.fn.appear.run();return r;};}});})(jQuery);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
}

.site-content {
  margin: 10px auto 500px; //это для создания слоя над футером
  max-width: 1263px;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="site-content">
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта</p>
    <p>Тут контент сайта<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Тут расположены какие-то элементы навигации</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: А он корректно работает во всех браузерах, включая мобильные?

Comment: @Deniskins вовсех, где проверял, работает корректно. Единственное - одному дизайнеру не понравился этот вариант на Mac'е, по причине того, что "у Mac'а и так скролл специфический". Но эту проблему можно решить, отключив `SmoothScroll` для определенных систем, используя `device.js`

Comment: Мммм, попробовал подключил,ломать ничего не ломает, все отображается норм, только что-то особо разницы не вижу в скролле...у него настройки как-то меняются?И подключать его просто подключить файл в src или нужно что-то еще добавлять?

Comment: @Deniskins да, для инициализации просто подключите файл к странцие. Настройки можно глянуть https://github.com/themicon/smoothscroll/blob/master/smoothscroll.js, начиная со строки 253

Comment: Все, спасибо друг.Будем считать что вопрос получил ответ..+1 к ауре!-)